# ignore some fileds when updating data

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

how can i ignore `username / email / phone` validation check for current user when updating?

update: i also used class validation but user is null and cant reach the current user id there

```
updateUserMutator(input: UpdateUserInput! ): User  @guard(with: ["api"])


input UpdateUserInput {
    name: String! @rules(apply: ["min:1","max:255", "required"])
    lastname: String! @rules(apply: ["min:1", "max:255", "required"])
    username: String! @rules(apply: ["min:1","max:12", "unique:users,username", "regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/"])
    email: String! @rules(apply: ["email", "unique:users,email", "required"])
    phone: String! @rules(apply: ["required", "unique:users,phone", "regex:/[0-9]{10}/"])
}


used class validation:

final class UpdateUserInputValidator extends Validator
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Return the validation rules.
     *
     * @return array<string, array<mixed>>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {

        // get user from context

        $id = auth()->id();
        return [
            'name' => ['sometimes', 'string', 'between:2,25'],
            'lastname' => ['sometimes', 'string', 'between:2,25'],
            'username' => [
                'sometimes',
                Rule::unique('users', 'username')->ignore($id, 'id'),
            ],
            'email' => [
                'sometimes',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($id, 'id'),
            ],
            'phone' => [
                'sometimes',
                'regex:/[0-9]{10}/',
                Rule::unique('users', 'phone')->ignore($id, 'id'),
            ],

        ];
    }
}
```

but user is null there.

Comment: When you say ignore, do you mean don’t fail due to those fields not being unique, or do you actually mean don’t bother validating them?

Comment: Read the documentation, here is how to setup a validator class https://lighthouse-php.com/master/security/validation.html#validator-classes

Comment: i want to skip for current user  for example when im updating the records its say: The username has already been taken @Peppermintology

Comment: @N69S i updated my post, accroding to docs i used class validation, but user is null and validation not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to update the upper part

```
input UpdateUserInput @validator {
    name: String
    lastname: String
    username: String
    email: String
    phone: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more options available to do so.

You could create a mutation for every field you want to update. This way you ignore the other fields and just update the field in request. (more work)

You can do it with your defined input but you should remove the ! characters which makes the fields required. The updated input might look like:

```
input UpdateUserInput {
    name:     String @rules(apply: ["sometimes", "min:1", "max:255"])
    lastname: String @rules(apply: ["sometimes", "min:1", "max:255"])
    username: String @rules(apply: ["sometimes", "min:1", "max:12", "unique:users,username", "regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/"])
    email:    String @rules(apply: ["sometimes", "email", "unique:users,email"])
    phone:    String @rules(apply: ["sometimes", "unique:users,phone", "regex:/[0-9]{10}/"])
}
```

With the second approach you just send the fields you want to change.